# Add column to nested table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out how to add a column into a nested table of BigQuery. I am not particularly tied to a method at this stage (CLI, Web UI, Python API, anything), so I am just wondering whether this is possible at all.

Comment: not directly but it is possible with some workaround - via select from your table with adding new field "on-fly" and save into new table (or overwrite existing one)

Comment: Maybe you could add a specific usecase o simple example, otherwise the question is quite generic and depends on your use case. However, as a general answer, @MikhailBerlyant words look like a good approach.

Comment: Sadly they don't have a python integration to do this easily. I am playing around with the python API to try and add a nested column, so I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas

If you scroll down this explains how to do what you want!

> Issue the bq update command and provide a JSON schema file that adds
> the nested field to the existing RECORD column's schema definition. If
> the table you're updating is in a project other than your default
> project, add the project ID to the dataset name in the following
> format: [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].
>
> `bq update [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] [SCHEMA]`
>
> `For Example:   bq update mydataset.mytable /tmp/myschema.json`
>
> ```
>   [
>     {
>       "mode": "REQUIRED",
>       "name": "column1",
>       "type": "STRING"
>     },
>     {
>       "mode": "REQUIRED",
>       "name": "column2",
>       "type": "FLOAT"
>     },
>     {
>       "fields": [
>         {
>           "mode": "NULLABLE",
>           "name": "nested1",
>           "type": "STRING"
>         },
>         {
>           "mode": "NULLABLE",
>           "name": "nested2",
>           "type": "STRING"
>         },
>         {
>           "mode": "NULLABLE",
>           "name": "nested3",
>           "type": "STRING"
>         }
>       ],
>       "mode": "REPEATED",
>       "name": "column3",
>       "type": "RECORD"
>     }
>   ]
> ```

You cans see above if your database didn't have the nested3 field, then using this command with the above described JSON you'd add it to the existing nested column set.

To obtain your tables original schema:

```
`bq show --schema --format=prettyjson mydataset.mytable > /tmp/myschema.json`
```

You can also achieve this through the python google.cloud API's by grabbing the table reference and updating the schema with the new columns added. It is the same methodology as above, but doing it in python pretty much.